# Lucene Query syntax using Boolean Clauses

Tags: solr, lucene

I have two fields in Lucene

1. type (can contain values like X, Y, Z)
2. date (contains values like 2015-18-10 etc)

I want to write following query: `(type = X and date=today's data) OR (type = anything except X).` 
How can I write this query using SHOULD, MUST, MUST_NOT? looks like there is no clause for these type of query.

Answer (score 1):

You can express the latter part using `*:* -type:X`, as this creates the set of all documents, and then subtracts the set of documents that has `type:X`. The `*:*` query is represented as [MatchAllDocsQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) in code.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your problem, I think the solution is just some combination of **BooleanQuery**, following is the code written in **Scala** to address the issue.

According to the documentation(in BooleanClause.java), MUST_NOT should be used with caution.

> Use this operator for clauses that *must not* appear in the   matching documents.Note that it is not possible to search for queries that only consist of a `MUST_NOT` clause.

```
  object LuceneTest extends App {

     val query = new BooleanQuery

     val subQuery1 = new BooleanQuery
     subQuery1.add(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "xx")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
     subQuery1.add(new TermQuery(new Term("date", "yy")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)

     val subQuery2 = new BooleanQuery
     // As mentioned above, so I put MatchAllDocsQuery here to avoid only containing MUST_NOT
     subQuery2.add(new MatchAllDocsQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)  
     subQuery2.add(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "xx")),BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)

     // subQuery1 and subQuery2 construct two subQueries respectively 
     // then use OR(i.e SHOULD in Lucene) to combine them 
     query.add(subQuery1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
     query.add(subQuery2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
     query

  }
```

Anyway, hope it helps.